# Setting a flag in LUIS for BING spell check

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I've connected bing spell check to my LUIS app, but I need to change the *mode* flag from 'proof' to 'spell'. Is there a possible way to do so while keeping the process automated.

Comment: for the bot that you're connecting your LUIS to, what language are you using, just so we can dig for a solution in the right area?

Answer (score 0):

The bing spell check API uses the default mode of "Proof" if you have integrated the API from your application/bot directly, Changing the mode value to "spell" should set the search to spell.

If you are adding the spell check endpoint URL directly with the LUIS API each and every call must include the required information for spelling corrections to work correctly.

The endpoint URL needs the spellCheck parameter to "true" along with the value of bing-spell-check-subscription-key.

> https://{region}.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/{appID}?subscription-key={luisKey}&spellCheck=**true**&bing-spell-check-subscription-key=**{bingKey}**&verbose=true&timezoneOffset=0&q={utterance}

The response from this endpoint for a misspelled word should suggest "alteredQuery" for the utterance passed. For example:

```
    {
  "query": "How far is the mountainn?",
  "alteredQuery": "How far is the mountain?",
  "topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "Concierge",
    "score": 0.183866
  },
  "entities": []
}
```

Comment: My questions is how to set mode to spell when calling spell check from LUIS

Comment: If you are using the spell check directly from the LUIS API **spellCheck=true** will set the mode to spell. If called directly the query parameter mode should be passed as 'Spell'